# I use google colab, and recently it has been extremely erratic and error prone ,even when there aren't any. Is this a characteristic of colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I used a new notebook within colab, and the same code worked just fine. This probably is a colab-related issue. 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzamQ.png
I'm still curious as to why it happened though.

```
def function(a,b,c): 
  temp = a

  for i in (b,c):

    if i > temp:

      temp = i

  return temp


function(43,54,12)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-127543af6285> in <module>()
----> 1 function(43,54,12)

NameError: name 'function' is not defined

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/atmRn.png
```

Comment: According to that traceback error, it thinks `function(43,54,12)` is the very first line of code.  So somehow it isn't seeing the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call to `function` should be done **after** the function is declared and defined as the interpreter first interpret the function and then evaluate the function call.

Make sure you call `function(43, 54, 12)` after the `function` itself is defined.

---

Also make sure you change the indentation from 2 space to 4 spaces when pressing Tab by going in `Tools > Setting > Editor` and changing:
[image]

---

Other than that after installing new packages, the kernel needs to be restarted. Sometimes just restarting the kernel refreshes the environment and fixes the issues.

Comment: As far as I can see, the call is after the definition.  Can you point out why you think it isn't?

Comment: I see as it does run on my system. But maybe the call might have been change when posting on stackoverflow....but that's also not the problem as seen via uploaded image.

Comment: @JohnGordon Maybe this is indentation problem.

Comment: @AnuragDhadse the code is on point, i tried it on IDLE and PyCharm where it runs just fine. Yesterday all the functions that i defined and ran on colab returned the same error, and the entire code was in the same cell , i.e both the definition and the call ran one after the other in the correct sequence. .

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for reformatting the code, i'm new to stack overflow and there was an error in pasting the code directly

Comment: Try shutting down and restarting the session...

Comment: I just wanna know if there is a prevalent problem with colab or it's just a freak occurence. @AnuragDhadse Using a new notebook worked

Comment: @WeReign The problem you experienced is rare occurrence. As said the problem got fixed just after restarting the session, so no. It's not prevalent. If you're problem is solved please accept an helpful answer.

Comment: @AnuragDhadse, the issue is back for me, but no problem ,sure